# How to sort products & categories based on customer group in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group, position

I am very new to magento. I need to provide a sort option for products as well as categories  based on customer group in admin panel.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: First you need to add the product attribute `customer_group`. Then for each product, set its value. Finally, add the attribute in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`.

Comment: but I want to set different position for same product based on customer group.so do i need to create 2 attributes ?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you  are trying to sort.

Comment: I have 2 customer groups : so category order for  both the groups should be different . Also , products order under category for both group should be different.